# How to pass data from coffeescript to rails as params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Hi I`am creating dynamic form in Rails, and I want to make a css of the form changed dynamic based on the list option.

This is my form:

```
  <%= form_for [@user, @user.characters.new] do |form| %>

    <%= form.label :name, "Imię" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= form.label :clan, "Klan" %>
    <%= form.select :clan, options_for_select([["a","a"],["b","b"]]) %><br/>
    <%= form.submit "Zapisz", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

So far I managed to connect select input with proper js.file:

```
$(document).on 'change', '#character_clan', ->
  chosen_clan = $(this).val()
  $.get window.location, ->
```

and my new.js.erb file is just `alert('hello world');` but it show as expected. Now I want to pass js chosen clan, as a clan param to my controller action. And I don't know where to put them, I tried to put them after function (->) but they don't get send, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I want to make a css of the form changed dynamic based on the list option` -> how does this connect with the controller?

Comment: I edited the question, with my form, it connects to js via select form which id is character_clan.

Comment: Okay, I still don't understand how this connects with your controller... You change your select box, then it's mean to ping it?

Comment: It connects by sending url, which is window.location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the data option of the $.get command. My coffeescript is not very good, but you should be able to do something like:

```
$.get 'window.location',
  name: 'John'
  time: '2pm'
```

Check out the docs at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: It is not straigh solution but it leads to solution so I mark it correct,